# How can I pass a variable defined in a Controller to my variables?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, variable, controller

In my Craft 3 plugin I would like to pass a variable defined in my Controller to my PluginVariable.php file. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you should improve your question with at least one example of what you'd like to achieve. When building a plugin, I couldn't think of a use case where passing a variable from a controller to the plugin variable would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest answer is "that's not possible," and the slightly longer answer is "that's not possible because Controllers and Variables have no reason to ever interact." If your Controller relies on a Variable (or vice versa), something is architecturally incorrect. There's no reason for the two to cross paths.

The purpose of a **Controller** is to receive input from a form, AJAX call, or to be used as an API endpoint. It can also be used via routing to show a particular template under particular conditions.

The purpose of a **Variable** is simply to render a value in your Twig template.